# Jquery Tinysort is sorting all divs instead of selected ones

Tags: jquery, sorting, html, jquery-plugins

I am using the Tinysort jquery plugin to re arrange some divs on a page.
http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/#defaultsorting

I asked a previous question on this and accepted the answer, but have noticed that its sorting ALL of the divs on the page and not just the ones I am wanting it to sort.

http://jsfiddle.net/L1010/zdCyB/1/

What I am trying to do is sort the divs with the id as question1, question2 etc. Each div has question and a number, and I want to sort them using this id, so instead of :

```
 <div id="question1"></div>
    <div id="question2"></div>
      <div id="question4"></div>
         <div id="question3"></div>
```

I would get :

```
  <div id="question1"></div>
    <div id="question2"></div>
                   <div id="question3"></div>
                <div id="question4"></div>
```

The problem is each of these divs contain divs so I need to sort only by the divs with the ID question* , otherwise it rearranges the insides of the divs too..

Comment: Your fiddle does not demonstrate the issue you are talking about. Does it?

Comment: No, it is one that someone gave me as an example on how to sort them by div, but I need to sort them by div id containing only the word question.

Comment: What it is doing is sorting the data inside the divs as well as the divs themselves, where as I only want to sort the divs with question contained within the ID

Answer (score 0):

You can sort just those DIVs with an id starting with "question" using:

```
$('div[id^="question"]').tsort("",{attr:"id"});
```